# How to use a variable in JsonPath filter

Tags: karate

I'm attempting to use a variable in the RHS of an JsonPath filter expression in a Karate test, similar to this:

```
* def name = 'A Name'
* def ids = $response[?(@.name == '#(name)')].id
```

If I use the literal string `'A Name'` in the RHS of the expression it works as expected.

I've tried various ways to get the variable to evaluate:
`'<name>'`, `"#(name)"`, etc.

I suspect it is because I'm mixing JsonPath parsing with Karate parsing perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this first: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

And what you are looking for is this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters

```
* def ids = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.kittens[?(@.name=='" + name + "')].id")
```

Comment: Yes, I read both documents prior, but I missed the critical party :-(:

`# using the karate object if the expression is dynamic
* def temp = karate.jsonPath(cat, "$.kittens[?(@.name=='" + bob.name + "')]")`

So for this specific case, a dynamic JsonPath expression, the Karate object is the required/recommended approach?

Comment: @kpschmidt yes that's right. also look at `karate.filter()` it can do the same thing more elegantly in some circumstances